# I can't make log in system

Tags: php, sql

Here is my login.php

```
   <?
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    include_once("connect.php");
    $user_ok = false;
    $usernamer=$_POST['Usernamer'];
    $passaword=$_POST['passsword'];
    $id = "SELECT id FROM websiteusers WHERE userName='$Usernamer' AND pass='$passaword' LIMIT 1";
    function evalLoggedUser($link,$id,$usernamer,$passaword){
        $sql = "SELECT ip FROM websiteusers WHERE userName='$Usernamer' AND pass='$passaword' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
        $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($link,$usernamer,$passaword,$id);
        if(isset($_POST['Login'])){
        if($user_ok == true){
        header("location: user.php?u=".$_POST["Usernamer"]);
        }else{
         echo "username was not found";
        }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

it gives erros like

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Even when I type the right username it echos `username was not found`

Comment: A few mistakes. The `$id` sql statement doesnt get used and references `id` initially - the actual sql in the function references `ip` ~ I guess they ought to be the same - probably id. Your call to the `evalLoggedUser` function has the args in the wrong sequence

Comment: There's probably a typo there: shouldn't it reAD $_post['passaword'] instead of passsword?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user no name of input is passsword

Comment: @RamRaider i have id and ip in my table

Comment: In the line `$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);`... What is the value of `$link` and where did it come from? Looks like it should simply be `$query = mysqli_query($sql);`. Can't really tell though with out more code being supplied.

Comment: It doesn't really matter from what I can tell - you only care as to whether or not the user exists and you do not return, from the function, the value of either `ip` or `id` - just true or false depending upon existance of valid user.

Comment: @Kuya from connect.php its connection to database

Comment: @RamRaider if i delete $id it gives error that says there should be four parameters

Comment: the `$id` parameter in your function doesn't do anything - you can remove it from the function as below

Comment: @RamRaider yes i got it now thanks i am not very good at php so i did not understand you:)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
   if($numrows < 0){
     return true;
   }
```

And your query should be:

```
$id = "SELECT id FROM websiteusers WHERE userName='$Usernamer' AND pass='$passaword' LIMIT 1";
//change $Usernamer to $usernamer
```

Comment: Because if you do `$numrows < 0` it will return false and will not go inside the if statement

Comment: I still don't get it. You want the function to return true if the db query returns more than zero rows, right? $numrows < 0 evaluates to true if you have an error of some kind, no? So you'd return true only if mysqli_num_rows() gives an error?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! Parameter one has to be a result set. That means you have to pass $query not your sql query

Comment: where? You mean on line 14?

Answer (score 0):

Several changes to the original with suitable comments

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ( isset( $_POST['Login'] ) ) {

        include_once("connect.php");
        $user_ok = false;

        $usernamer=$_POST['Usernamer'];
        $passaword=$_POST['passsword'];
        /* to debug */
        echo "POSTED username:".$usernamer." POSTED password: ".$passaword;

        /*
            this gets passed as a parameter to the function but never used...
            $id = "SELECT id FROM websiteusers WHERE userName='$Usernamer' AND pass='$passaword' LIMIT 1";
        */
        function evalLoggedUser( $conx, $u, $p ){
            /* To use the variables above ( $usernamer & $passaword ) you would need to declare them as global within the function */
            /* I assumed, perhaps wrongly, that this ought to have been id rather than ip */

            $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `websiteusers` WHERE `userName`='$u' AND `pass`='$p' LIMIT 1";

           /* to debug */
           exit( "PARAM Username:".$u ."<br />PARAM Password:". $p ."<br />sql:" .$sql );

            $query = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
            $numrows = mysqli_num_rows( $query );

            /* previously the function only returned a value if there was a recordset */
            return ( $numrows > 0 ) ? true : false;
        }


        /*
            The sequence of parameters was incorrect 
        */
        $user_ok = evalLoggedUser( $link, $usernamer, $passaword );

        if( isset( $_POST['Login'] ) ){
            if( $user_ok === true ){
                header("location: user.php?u=".$usernamer );
            }else{
                echo "username was not found";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: so it deleted all errors but still echos username was not found

Comment: For a test, try adding `exit($sql)` after the sql statement has been created ( but not executed ) in the `evalLoggedUser` function. Look at the sql that gets echoed to screen - does it look correct? Can you run that sql in your mysql client / gui and get data returned?

Comment: no it shows this SELECT `userId` FROM `websiteusers` WHERE `userName`='' AND `pass`='' LIMIT 1

Comment: @qwaaz - is this now fixed?

Comment: what did the debug statements reveal? Are the correct values getting POSTed? Is anything getting POSTed?